# How to write if statements to print various strings

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am writing a function that checks if two numbers in a list are within a certain range and then print various statements if one number is in the range or if both numbers are in the range. My problem is that the right statements aren't being printed under the right conditions despite the statements looking fine.

```
def qualitative_reading(input_list):
  humidity = 0
  temp = 0
  humid_round= round(input_list[0])
  temp_round= round(input_list[1])

  if humid_round in range(39, 61, 1):
    humidity = 1
  else:
    humidity = 0

  if temp_round in range(67, 75, 1):
    temp = 1
  else:
    temp = 0

  if humidity + temp ==2:
    print('The room is comfortable')
  elif temp == 1 & humidity == 0:
    print("Ideal conditions for bacteria and virus")
    print('The room is not comfortable to be in')
  elif temp == 0 & humidity == 1:
    print('The room is not comfortable to be in')
    print('Energy being wasted')
  elif humidity + temp ==0:
    print('The room is not comfortable to be in')
```

[image: Sample output using similar code]
[image: Sample output using similar code]

Comment: Why do you add humidity and temp in the last if statement?

Comment: Why use `range` for this? And please show sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: the range represents the acceptable numbers. If inputs fall within the range the respective variables are assigned a number 1 else 0 if they dont.

Comment: @BlueRobin There was no particular reason to add them. I could have done it like the other if conditins.

Comment: Not exactly because for inputs [10,80] the expected output should be "The room is not comfortable to be in"

Comment: Replace `&` by `and`.

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that there were two outputs, and that the second sentence is used multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this instead

```
def qualitative_reading(input_list):
  humidity = False
  temp = False
  humid_round= input_list[0]
  temp_round= input_list[1]

  humidity = 39 <= humid_round < 61
  temp = 67 <= temp_round < 75

  if humidity and temp:
    print('The room is comfortable')
  elif temp and not humidity:
    print("Ideal conditions for bacteria and virus")
    print('The room is not comfortable to be in')
  elif not temp and humidity:
    print('The room is not comfortable to be in')
    print('Energy being wasted')
  elif not humidity and not temp:
    print('The room is not comfortable to be in')
```

I suspect that the problem lies with the fact that you are using & but python uses the keyword `and`.

Some of the other things I noticed were:

The use of range is not very applicable here so you can use an if statement instead.

`humidity` and `temp` seem to only have two values, so they can be turned into booleans.

Comment: Perhaps even nicer: `humidity = 39 <= humid_round < 61`. The comparison result already equates to True or False, and you can use Python's chained comparison: `a < b < c` and the like.

Comment: Can you further explain why range isn't applicable here?

Comment: @ImmanuelNiiOdaiOdarteifio Range only works for integers. If you use simple greater or lesser than comparisons, you can use floats as input as well. For example, `5.5 in range(4, 6)` is False, but `4 <= 5.5 < 6` is True.

Comment: You can leave the rounding of numbers out, since you don't use range.

Comment: "you are using & but python used the keyword and.": this!

Comment: @9769953 Thanks for the tip. I always forget python has such nice compact comparisons.